# How can PERCENTILE_CONT and PERCENTILE_DIST be non-deterministic?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

According to the MSDN doc: [PERCENTILE_CONT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/percentile-cont-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), both of the functions are non-deterministic.

How can these two functions be non-deterministic? Any example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On page you posted, you can find link to another page:

[Deterministic and Nondeterministic Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/deterministic-and-nondeterministic-functions?view=sql-server-2017)

where is clearly stated:

> All aggregate functions are deterministic unless they are specified with the OVER and ORDER BY clauses. For a list of these functions, see Aggregate Functions (Transact-SQL).

That's why `PERCENTILE_CONT` is non-deterministic. It uses `ORDER BY` clause, which can be source of non-determinism, if you don't specify this caluse unique-ly, i.e. there will be ties - there is no guarantee that tied records will be ordered in the same way every time you attempt ordering.

Comment: Given a particular SQL Server with the settings unchanged, the result should be deterministic though.

Comment: @ca9163d9 Well, it's very unlikely for result to change, but it might change. That's why they're marked as non-deterministic. I have used `OVER (ORDER BY...)` for ages and haven't witnessed strange behaviour ever. But it can happen :)

Comment: @ca9163d9 it can happen with parallelism easily. Single-threaded sorting is also sensitive to the order in which input rows are received. This can change through b-tree layout changes (e.g. defragmenting).

Comment: @usr I was thinking the order changes by the culture settings. However, it seems very unstable if the order changes because of parallelism or physical storage.

Comment: @ca9163d9 - the rules are surprisingly simple, but most people still seem to have odd expectations. If you supply an `ORDER BY` clause that defines a *unique* ordering then the results are deterministic. If you *under-specify* the `ORDER BY` clause, the results are not. People (unreasonably) expect that if they under-specify the `ORDER BY` then some kind of "default" ordering will apply to break ties. Theres no such guarantee.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever is there any example of "under-specify the ORDER BY"?

Comment: @ca9163d9 I stated that in my answer: "there will be ties - there is no guarantee that tied records will be ordered in the same way every time you attempt ordering"

Answer (score 1):

The sort order could have ties in which case the order is generally undefined in SQL Server.

Comment: So this could be deterministic to, then, no?

Comment: @scsimon it could be but it's not. It's good for performance to not force SQL Server to apply an arbitrary order if no order is required.